# How to test spring 5 controllers with Junit5

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, junit5, spring-test-mvc

I'm trying to test my Spring 5 web controllers with JUnit 5.
The two way to test controller (as mentionned in spring documentation) always give me null pointer.

This is my test class

```
import com.lacunasaurus.gamesexplorer.test.configuration.TestBackEndConfiguration;
import com.lacunasaurus.gamesexplorer.test.configuration.TestWebConfig;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebAppConfiguration()
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestWebConfig.class, TestBackEndConfiguration.class})
public class TestAuthenticationCreateAccountController {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        // this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new AuthenticationCreateAccountController()).build();

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getAccount() throws Exception {
        // Here i've got an null pointer
        mockMvc.perform(get("/"));
    }

}
```

Here my web configuration for tests

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.lacunasaurus.gamesexplorer.web"})
public class TestWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer, ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

}
```

And now my controller

```
  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("/create-account")
  public class AuthenticationCreateAccountController {

   @Autowired
   UserAccountValidator accountValidator;

   @Autowired
   AuthenticationService authenticationService;

   @GetMapping
   public String navigate() {
       return "authentication/create-account";
   }

   @ModelAttribute("userAccount")
   public UserAccount setDefaultAccount() {

       return new UserAccount();
   }

   @InitBinder
   protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

       binder.addValidators(accountValidator);
   }

   @PostMapping
   public String createAccount(@Validated UserAccount userAccount, BindingResult bindingResult) {

       if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
           return "authentication/create-account";
       }

       authenticationService.createUserAccount(userAccount);

       return "authentication/create-account";
   }
  }
```

EDIT : The stacktrace given by the IDE

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException at com.lacunasaurus.gamesexplorer.test.controller.TestAuthenticationCreateAccountController.getAccount(TestAuthenticationCreateAccountController.java:41)

Results :

Tests in error: 
    TestAuthenticationCreateAccountController.getAccount:41 NullPointer
```

I've got already test my backend with junit 5 and spring and everything work well.

Thanks to thoses who will help me to understand how to test controller :)

Comment: You're asking about an exception, but don't post the stack trace of the exception. Reading it is the very first step in fixing the problem. Note that you're mixing JUnit 4 and JUnit 5 classes and annotations, which doesn't make sense. Read the documentation of JUnit 5.

Comment: OK, so now we know that what is null is mockMvc. Why is it null? It's supposed to be initialized in the setup() method. So, if it's null, it means that setup() isn't being called. Why isn't it called? Because it's not annotated with any JUnit 5 annotation that would make it called. `Before` is a JUnit 4, and thus irrelevant, annotation. So is `RunWith`.

Comment: Yes sorry, i added the stack trace but this one isn't too much explicit

If I ask for help here it's because there is something  that i don't see in the documentation and an invitation to read it doesn't help me too much to target the problem especially if your experience allowed you to immediately understand it :(

Anyway, with your highlighting of the use of Junit 4 (which I absolutely do not refer to in my pom.xml) I could see that the problem came from the annotation @Before.

Thanks to you :)

Comment: It's very explicit. It says something is null, and thus causes a NullPointerException, at line 41, inside the method getAccount() of TestAuthenticationCreateAccountController. The only thing that can be null at this line is MockMvc. the rest is deduced from that. I invite people to read because I notice that most newbies don't even read, not even once, the documentation. They try random things, and then ask for help. Reading the documentation takes some time, but allows getting the big picture, discovering features, and not making stupid mistakes. In the end, the gain is huge.

Comment: We were writing at the same time, indeed the problem came from before that I changed to BeforeAll.
Very good analysis;)

Answer (score 9):

The new test for controllers :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebAppConfiguration()
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestWebConfig.class, TestBackEndConfiguration.class})
@TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class TestAuthenticationCreateAccountController {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    void getAccount() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/toto")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Comment: remove @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class). It is not needed. This was replaced with @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) in JUnit5 and you already have that.

Comment: @BeforeAll methods must have a void return type, must not be private, and must be static by default:

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.3/api/index.html?org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeAll.html

Comment: This works for keycloak too. Just mentioning to help seekers :D

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Junit5, See this [reference](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-tips)

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)  // For Junit5
public class TestAuthenticationCreateAccountController {

    @Mock
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @InjectMocks
    private AuthenticationCreateAccountController ac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach // For Junit5
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(ac).build();

    }

    @Test
    public void getAccount() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't this new up mockMvc for each test? Doesn't it only need to be created once?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use JUnit Jupiter, you must use autoconfigure MockMvc. This is a help to resolve all related configuration.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebAppConfiguration()
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

Comment: If you use the annotation `@WebMvcTest` you automatically get the `AutoConfigureMockMvc` and a few others

Answer (score -4):

```
@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: kindly have your answer more descriptive and a link would be also good.