# Unit testing for spring boot RESTFUL Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, mockmvc

I am trying to do unit testing for spring boot RESTFUL controller but I am receiving a null pointer exception. The application has a `StudentController` which depends on a `StudentService`. 
Here is the controller code:

```
package com.demo.student.demo.controller;

import com.demo.student.demo.annotation.ApiDescription;
import com.demo.student.demo.entity.Student;
import com.demo.student.demo.entity.StudentDto;
import com.demo.student.demo.service.StudentService;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/students")
@Api(description = "This is a general description for StudentController RESTFUL Controller")
public class StudentController {

    private StudentService studentService;
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public StudentController(ModelMapper modelMapper, StudentService studentService){
        this.studentService = studentService;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }

    private StudentDto convertToDto(Student student) {
        StudentDto studentDto = modelMapper.map(student, StudentDto.class);
        return studentDto;
    }

    private Student convertToEntity(StudentDto studentDto) {
        Student student = modelMapper.map(studentDto, Student.class);
        return student;
    }

    @GetMapping
    @ApiOperation("Returns a list of all students in the system.")
    @ApiDescription("FIND_ALL_STUDENTS.md")
    public List<StudentDto> findAll(){
        List<Student> students = studentService.findAl();
        return students.stream()
                .map(student -> convertToDto(student))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    @ApiOperation("Returns a specific Student by his/her identifier. 404 if does not exist.")
    @ApiDescription("FIND_STUDENT_BY_ID.md")
    public StudentDto findById(@PathVariable("id") long id){
        return convertToDto(studentService.findById(id));
    }

    @PostMapping
    @ApiOperation("Creates/Updates a new Student.")
    @ApiDescription("SAVE_OR_UPDATE_STUDENT.md")
    public StudentDto saveOrUpdate(@RequestBody StudentDto studentDto) {
        Student student = convertToEntity(studentDto);
        student.setUsername(student.getEmail() + "----" + student.getId());
        Student studentCreated = studentService.saveOrUpdate(student);
        return convertToDto(studentCreated);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @ApiOperation("Deletes a Student from the system. 404 if the Student's identifier is not found.")
    @ApiDescription("DELETE_STUDENT_BY_ID.md")
    public void deleteById(@PathVariable("id") long id){
        studentService.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

And here is the service implementation code:

```
package com.demo.student.demo.service;

import com.demo.student.demo.entity.Student;
import com.demo.student.demo.exception.StudentNotFoundException;
import com.demo.student.demo.repository.StudentRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;


@Service
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    public StudentServiceImpl(StudentRepository studentRepository){
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Student> findAl() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Student findById(long id) {
        return  studentRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new StudentNotFoundException(id));
    }

    @Override
    public Student saveOrUpdate(Student student) {
        studentRepository.save(student);
        return student;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(long id) {
        if(this.findById(id) != null)
            studentRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

And this is the test class for the controller:

```
package com.demo.student.demo.controller;

import com.demo.student.demo.entity.Student;
import com.demo.student.demo.service.StudentService;
import com.demo.student.demo.service.StudentServiceImpl;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

@WebMvcTest(StudentController.class)
class StudentControllerTest {

    private final static String URI = "/v1/students";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private StudentService studentService;

    @Test
    void findAll() throws Exception {    
        // given
        Student student = new Student(1, "test", "test@test.test");
        List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(student);
        given(studentService.findAl()).willReturn(students);

        // when + then
        mockMvc.perform(get(URI))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().json("[{'id':1,'email':'test@test.test'}]"));
    }

}
```

Here is also the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo.student</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run the test I receive a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION pointing to a code line in the `StudentController` class where the student service retrieves all the student data: `List<Student> students = studentService.findAl();`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.demo.student.demo.controller.StudentController.findAll
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Should be because the mockbean is not injected to MockMvc. Can you try adding '@InjectMocks' above `private MockMvc mockMvc;`

Comment: @AbbinVarghese, the same. Nothing changed.

Comment: Remove your `@BeforeEach` and `@RunWith`. Spring Boot already does all of that for you and as you are using jUnit5 (judging from the `@BeforeEach` you shouldn't use the `@RunWith` as that is for JUnit4).

Comment: Check the updated code @M.Deinum

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your test class this way.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

Autowire this:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;
```

This is just a class variable:

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;
```

Your setup method:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
}
```

Before this line:

```
given(studentService.findAl()).willReturn(students);
```

Create:

```
StudentService studentService = org.mockito.Mockito.mock(StudentService.class);
```

It should run.

Comment: I changed it in @BeforeEach but now it gives Null Pointer Exception at that line in the test class: 
`given(studentService.findAl()).willReturn(students);`

Comment: Mock the interface. Not the implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I mocked the interface itself


`StudentService studentService = mock(StudentService.class);`

Comment: Do it in the test class. Before this line given(studentService.findAl()).willReturn(students); Remove it from beforeEach method. Your setup should be annotated @before. If you need a beforeEach class, have it separately.

Comment: I moved that line `StudentService studentService = mock(StudentService.class);` to `findAll()` test method, before 'given' section. Still an error as the one described in the question above.

Comment: With @WebMvcTest(StudentController.class), you don't need mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .standaloneSetup(StudentController.class)
                .build(); inside the beforeEach Setup method.

Comment: I removed it but now have a null pointer exception at that line: `mockMvc.perform(get(URI)).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().json("[{'id':1,'email':'test@test.test'}]"))`

Comment: Let me show you a configuration I use in the answer section so you can try.

Comment: Okay, I'm with you.

Comment: But with `@SpringBootTest` it's turned into an `Integration Test` not a `Unit Test`

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49096577/how-to-test-spring-5-controllers-with-junit5

Comment: Thanks alot. The answer you sent me in the last comment put me on the right track. Great thanks to you. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things with your test, first you are mixing JUnit4 and JUnit5, don't, second you are trying to work against the Spring Boot created mock, don't. Finally you are creating a new mock for the service and register behavior.

1. Remove the `@RunWith` annotation, that is for JUnit4 tests and not needed with JUnit5.
2. Remove your `@BeforeEach` method, as that interferes with the prepared `MockMvc` by Spring Boot (through the `@WebMvcTest`) and the mock created by `@MockBean`.
3. Remove `StudentService studentService = mock(StudentService.class);` from your test method. `@MockBean` already creates a mock. This creates a new mock, not tied to the controller.
4. The version of Spring Boot used (2.0.x) doesn't yet have an `@WebMvcTest` that includes the `@ExtendWith` annotation (as of Spring Boot 2.1.x). So add that as well to use the proper execution model.

**pro-tip:** Remove the no-args constructor and `@Autowired` from your `StudentController`, Spring is smart enough to pick the single constructor.

Comment: You can check my question I updated it with your recommendations. Still got a NPE at that line: `mockMvc.perform(get(URI)).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().json("[{'id':1,'email':'test@test.test'}]"));`

Comment: Remove the line mocking the service from your test method, as stated that is what `@MockBean` already does. You are trying to outsmart the framework.

Comment: Updated the question above. Now, it's NPE at `given(studentService.findAl()).willReturn(students);`

Comment: make sure you are using the proper runner (and not that it is still using JUnit4).

Comment: I uploaded the pom.xml, so you can check it.

Comment: Thanks alot. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found an answer, to add `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` in order to work in JUnit5.
So, my controller test class would be:

```
package com.demo.student.demo.controller;

import com.demo.student.demo.entity.Student;
import com.demo.student.demo.service.StudentService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest
class StudentControllerTest {

    private final static String URI = "/v1/students";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private StudentService studentService;

    @Test
    void findAll() throws Exception {
        // given
        Student student = new Student(1, "test", "test@test.test");
        List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(student);
        given(studentService.findAl()).willReturn(students);

        // when + then
        mockMvc.perform(get(URI))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().json("[{'id':1,'email':'test@test.test'}]"));
    }

}
```

And also here is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo.student</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I assumed you where on a more recent version of Spring Boot in which the `@WebMvcTest` itself is annotated with `@ExtendWith`. For future questions please include the framework versions you are using.